# Starshipit In Magento2.3.3

Tags: magento2

I have integrated starshipit in my magento2.3.3 store and I am using MSI feature when I try to ship order my Magento exception log show this error and status failed.

> [2020-01-10 06:38:00] report.CRITICAL: The shipment couldn't be saved.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The
>   shipment couldn't be saved. at
>   /var/www/au/releases/20200109053408/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/ShipmentRepository.php:150,
>   Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Source
>   item not found by source code: default and sku: PLA10009MONW. at
>   /var/www/au/releases/20200109053408/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api/Model/GetSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku.php:59)"}
>   []

Comment: Are there any other messages as this is a very limited error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue relates to using a 3rd party shipping platform Starshipit. They do not link to more than one inventory source. This is what starship has responded to me with after raising a ticket.

> "Currently out Magento integration only supports having one inventory location and has not met any demand to change this fact. I am in discussions with our development team to assess the required work involved with this. I will update you as soon as I have further information."

I am waiting for Starshipit to respond but in the meantime  I have found the only fix was to disable the magento MSI modules.

[Disable stock check / decrease when shipping an order in Magento 2.3.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277993/disable-stock-check-decrease-when-shipping-an-order-in-magento-2-3-1/316074#316074)